# Help with running software

Tags: apt

I am new to Ubuntu and a basic user, I have downloaded some software called 'rovergauge' but struggling to get this up and running, can someone help,please.

Comment: Please add more details about how you downloaded the software. Assuming you downloaded a `.deb` file, please see answer above.

Comment: @ArturMeinild not what he means ;) David see https://github.com/colinbourassa/rovergauge on how to proceed.

Comment: @Rinzwind and from [this link](https://github.com/colinbourassa/rovergauge/releases/tag/11.1.0) you download a `.deb` file. So I'm wrong how? 

Comment: You've provided no clear details that we can really assist with. We don't know what Ubuntu product you're using (is it a *deb* based system, or a *snap* only system of Ubuntu?). We don't know what release of that product (*snap* packages run on all *supported* systems, however *deb* packages are built for specific release(s) and we don't know what you're using).  Please be clear with details.

Comment: Installing the .deb file `sudo apt install /path/to/package.deb` would be the easiest way to install it because this command tries to install the package's dependencies too.